# Memory profiling of a multithreaded haskell program

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, profiling

I have a Snap web app which serves some JS files and 1-pixel images (it's main task is to rather work fast then serve huge html/media content). There are several servers behind HAProxy.

I upgraded it from GHC 7.6 to 7.8, also upgrading some libs. After upgrade, app started leaking little by little (on all servers), ending in OOM every 15 minutes on 8GB-RAM machines (and much longer on 16Gb) and restarting afterwards.

The problem is, if I compile app for profiling and run app for some time, I can't see any memory leaks anymore. It just consumes 1 CPU and works in constant small memory.

So I wanted to ask for some general advices on how to find such a bottleneck, if running under profiling doesn't help much.

UPDATE: I noticed after playing with an app that if I remove `-A100M` runtime option it doen't OOM that fast, but with default value HAProxy's "sessions" gets to it's limit (so, basically it chokes). I'm playing with different RTS options now, hope some will help getting both, performance and long-lived memory consumption.

UPDATE 2: just for the record, I found that with `-A30` rts option app, while being memory hungry, lives quite well. 8Gb machines OOM-kill app, but 16Gb one looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYjrV.png (green line is "RAM available", you can see deploy-procedure which restarted app on a graph). I'm happy with the result, but would be glad to know any techniques to profile memory of multi-threaded app anyway.

UPDATE 3: I'm voting to close this question as "too broad". In general, I see that if such generic set of tools that'll let you profile memory easier would exist, they'd definitely be documented elsewhere on wiki etc.

Comment: You realize this post is missing lots of vital information? What apps? What libraries involved? What OS? What CPU? Where's the source? Where's the profiles? What runtime options did you use? What profiling tools (threadscope)? What literature have you researched (like, http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch15.html#sec_conc-tuning)? This could be a regression from ghc-7.6 to 7.8, but have you checked their bug tracker (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug).

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 I am providing the only information I think is relevant at the time. Most of your questions aren't concrete enough to answer (like "what apps?"). I tried different runtime options (and profiling ones also). How is threadscope relevant to memory-profiling? I used it in past, but I don't think it's relevant here. I didn't read the book, but once again, does it have chapters regarding memory profiling?

I don't know if it's a regression or not. To tell that -- we first need to pin-point the problem somehow.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 so, I'm glad to answer any concrete questions that would give some result which would help getting closer to solution. Feel free to ask!

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 added a bit more details, hope this helps

Comment: can you show us a code snippet that exhibits the behaviour?

Comment: @jev that's the problem. It's a huge web app, and main goal right now is to at least get a feeling which subset of it is leaking. After that I would try to reproduce the problem in a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used it myself but maybe [ticky-ticky profiling](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Debugging/TickyTicky) could help? It's supposed to be immune to the optimization changes caused by ordinary profiling, but at the cost of being harder to interpret.

Basically compile and link the relevant modules with the `-ticky` and `-rtsopts` flags, and run with `+RTS -rfoo.ticky` flag to get heaps of data in `foo.ticky`.